# Multiple router views using vue router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

**Explanation:** I have `App.vue`, `Management.vue`, `Login.vue` and `Register.vue` pages. And I have another `folder` saying `management_pages`. In that management folder I have `Products.vue` and `Suppliers.vue` files.

**What I'm expecting to do:** In the App.vue I want the `router-view` to be for `Management.vue`, `Login.vue` and `Register.vue` only. And when we go to my `/management` route I want the `router-view` to be Products.vue (/products) and Suppliers.vue (/suppliers) since the layout of both files are in my `Management.vue` file. How can I handle such thing?

I have tried this:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from "vue-router";
import Products from "../pages/Products.vue";
import Suppliers from "../pages/Suppliers.vue";
import ErrorPage from "../pages/ErrorPage.vue";
import Login from "../pages/Login.vue";


const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes: [
        {
            path: "/products",
            name: "Products",
            component: Products,
        },
        {
            path: "/suppliers",
            name: "Suppliers",
            component: Suppliers,
        },
        {
            path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
            name: "ErrorPage",
            component: ErrorPage,
        },
        {
            path: "/login",
            name: "Login",
            component: Login,
        },
    ],
});

export default router;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not clear what do you want, would you please specify, the page you want to display with its wanted path?

Comment: The question lacks clear problem statement. It's unclear what's the meaning of "What I'm expecting to do" section and what problem you currently have with it. If you have some requirements regarding a layout, diagrams and component code would be helpful. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . Questions are downvoted and not answered not because other users are cruel or not willing to help but because they are asked in a way they cannot get a good answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your question is vague, but since you are struggling I will try provide an answer. If I understand your question correctly, you want to [define nested routes](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html) for `/management/products` and `/management/suppliers`.

First you need to add a `<router-view></router-view>` to your Management.vue component, where you want the content of `Products.vue` and `Suppliers.vue`.

Then you need to define the products and supplier routes as children of the management route, like:

```
routes: [
    {
         path: "/management",
         name: "Management",
         component: Management,
         children: [
            {
                 path: "products",
                 name: "Products",
                 component: Products,
             },
             {
                 path: "suppliers",
                 name: "Suppliers",
                 component: Suppliers,
              },
         ]
    },
    {
            path: "/login",
            name: "Login",
            component: Login,
    },
    {
            path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
            name: "ErrorPage",
            component: ErrorPage,
    },
],
```

Be sure to also import the `Management.vue` in your router file.

If you don't want `/management` to be a accessible route, you can [define a redirect](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/redirect-and-alias.html) on the `/management` path to one of the children, like:

```
redirect: { name: 'Products' }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice :-) good luck!